# Symfony Event Listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, listener

Hi I'm tring to do a Symfony event listener following this documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

```
<?php

namespace FM\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use FM\AdminBundle\Entity\Address\BillingAddress;

class BillingAdressListener
{
    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function listenBillingAdress(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if(!$entity instanceof BillingAddress){
            return;
        }

        $this->postPersist($args);
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $billingAdress = $args->getEntity();

        dump($billingAdress); die();
    }
}
```

service.yml

```
billing_adress.listener:
        class: FM\AppBundle\EventListener\BillingAdressListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: listenBillingAdress }
```

But nothing is happening when I'm submitting a form with the **BillingAddress** object.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Have you create the suscriber class ? Else go see Doctrine doc : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

Comment: How do you raise `listenBillingAdress` event?

Comment: I'm not doing an event *Suscriber* but an event *Listener*

Comment: Review the example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#configuring-the-listener-subscriber.  The event has to be a Doctrine event such as postPersist,  I'm surprised that using listenBillingAdress is not generating an error.  Double check that your service file is being loaded as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was not doing a **Persist** but an **Update**.

It works with an **Persist**.

Here is my code now:

```
<?php

namespace FM\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use FM\AdminBundle\Entity\Address\BillingAddress;

class BillingAddressListener
{
    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if(!$entity instanceof BillingAddress){
            return;
        }

        $this->addNameToUser($args);
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function addNameToUser(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        /** @var BillingAddress $billingAdress */
        $billingAdress = $args->getEntity();
        $user = $billingAdress->getOwner();

        if(empty($user->getFirstName())) $user->setFirstName($billingAdress->getFirstName());
        if(empty($user->getLastName())) $user->setLastName($billingAdress->getLastName());
    }
}
```

And I have to call the prePersist method.
I was doing the contrary.

```
billing_address.listener:
    class: FM\AppBundle\EventListener\BillingAddressListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called Entity Listeners in Doctrine. Here is [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners).

Don't forget to add your entity listener in mapping. For example xml mapping:

```
<entity name="AppBundle\Entity\AssignmentAttempt" table="app_assignment_attempt" >
    <entity-listeners>
        <entity-listener class="AppBundle\EntityListener\AssignmentAttemptListener">
            <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="prePersist"/>
            <lifecycle-callback type="preUpdate" method="preUpdate"/>
        </entity-listener>
    </entity-listeners>
    <!-- Rest mapping -->
</entity>
```

In config you can simply add

```
app.entity_listener.assignment_attempt:
     class: AppBundle\EntityListener\AssignmentAttemptListener
     tags:
         - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```